# JACOB get HWND of window

Tags: java, com, hwnd, jacob

I'm looking to get the native Window handle of a powerpoint window using Java / JACOB. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.documentwindow.hwnd%28v=office.14%29.aspx) seems to suggest it should be possible to just grab the "HWND" property, so I'm attempting that like so:

```
app = new ActiveXComponent("PowerPoint.Application");
Dispatch presentations = app.getProperty("Presentations").toDispatch();
presentation = Dispatch.call(presentations, "Open", fileLocation).toDispatch();
EnumVariant windows = new EnumVariant(Dispatch.get(presentation, "Windows").toDispatch());
Dispatch window = windows.nextElement().toDispatch();
Dispatch.get(window, "HWND"); //Exception here
```

However, I don't seem to be able to get the window handle this way - I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: A COM exception has been encountered:
At Invoke of: HWND
Description: 80020003 / Member not found.

at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Native Method)
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Dispatch.java:625)
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.get(Dispatch.java:788)
at tester.PowerpointSlideShowRunner.<init>(PowerpointSlideShowRunner.java:54)
at tester.PowerpointSlideShowRunner.main(PowerpointSlideShowRunner.java:154)
```

Is this a bug in the library, or am I doing something wrong / misunderstanding something here? The latter is quite possible as I'm entirely new to Jacob. Either way, how should I grab the HWND of the Powerpoint window using JACOB?

Comment: "The MSDN documentation seems to suggest..." : what MSDN documentation? Not the PowerPoint object model documentation, as far as I can see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff744694.aspx

Comment: @ChrisDickson I was actually looking at the link I've just updated the question with, but I could have been looking in the wrong place, sorry about that! If so, then have you any idea how best to grab the HWND some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN documentation you have linked is for the .NET Interop assembly which wraps the PowerPoint COM object model for use by .NET managed code, rather than for the COM object model itself.

The metadata in the interop assembly shows that there is actually an undocumented `HWND` property present in the COM interface to a `DocumentWindow`, but it carries the special type library attribute `FUNCFLAG_FRESTRICTED` which [indicates that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms221143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it

> is intended for system-level functions or functions that type browsers
>   should not display.

I imagine this is the reason that your attempt to call this property by name through the `DocumentWindow` dispatch interface is failing.

However, the Interop assembly metadata also shows that the DISPID (dispatch identifier) for this restricted property is the value `0x7e4`. I'm not very familiar with the JACOB library but I believe there is an override which allows you to get the value of a property by DISPID rather than by name:

```
Dispatch.get(window, 0x7e4);
```

I suggest you give this a try.

Comment: Thanks, this DISPID does indeed give me back an object - but one that doesn't give me the HWND int directly unfortunately, it seems to contain two DISPIDs - 0x1 and 0x4. 1 gives me the reference to the presentation window again, and 4 gives me an int but it always seems to be 34, not the window handle. Any ideas?

Comment: "it seems to contain two DISPIDs" ... I don't understand what you're saying here. The object returned is a `Variant`: what is its underlying type (`getvt()`)?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. The underlying type is a `Dispatch` (`getvt()` returns 9), so I can grab the Dispatch object by `getDispatch()`. I'm unsure of the type of this particular Dispatch though, and looping through the DISPIDs seems to only produce two, 0x1 and 0x4. If I call 0x1 (via `Dispatch.get(hwnd, 0x1)` assuming hwnd is the dispatch I got from calling 0x7e4 above), then I get a dispatch returned that's equal to the window object, if I call 0x4 then I get an integer returned that always seems to be 34 (which as far as I can tell isn't the HWND.)